# Pressing back button to viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager working well, when I click on a view/page it opens a new activity, but when I want to press back to go to the viewpager the app closes. How would I get the viewpager to open properly to the current page when I press the back button?

I know it is supposed to so here is the viewpager code:

```
public class LogoQuizActivity extends Activity {

private
class PageListener extends SimpleOnPageChangeListener{
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    //Log.i(TAG, "page selected " + position);
       currentPage = position;
}
}    

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage);
    myPager.setPadding(0, 150, 0, 0);

    PageListener pageListener = new PageListener();
    myPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageListener);

}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = null; // this comes first
         int resId = 0;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            resId = R.layout.farleft;
            view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

            break;
        case 1:
            resId = R.layout.left;
            view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

            break;
        case 2:
            resId = R.layout.middle;
            view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

            break;
        case 3:
            resId = R.layout.right;
            view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

            break;
        case 4:
            resId = R.layout.farright;
            view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

            break;
        }


        view.setTag(position);
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                int position = (Integer) view.getTag();
                Log.v("Log_tag", "Here image is clicked" + position);

                if(position == 0){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LogoQuizActivity.this,
                            LevelOne.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }

                if(position == 1){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                            LevelTwo.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                if(position == 2){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                            LevelThree.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                if(position == 3){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                            LevelFour.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                if(position == 4){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                            LevelFive.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });


        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

        return view;


    }



    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }       

}

}
```

I'm not sure if it's to do with restore state method or return null in parcelable savestate. It could be completely obvious so thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're throwing an `Exception`, then you need to mention what kind and post your **log**. Also, it doesn't sound like you're using `ViewPager` correctly, but then again you haven't given anyone much to work with. You should try to ask a more specific question and preferably include any relevant code.

Comment: .. it's not throwing an exception. I'm merely asking for some help and advice on this. The question is not vague and refers to reopening the viewpager once its view has been destroyed. Try and be more constructive

Comment: @Pete he is kinda correct. If your viewpager is in its own activity and you launch a new activity by clicking it, you should get back to the viewpager activity by clicking the back button. We must be missing some info...

Comment: @Warpzit see I didn't know that, will edit my question shortly.

Comment: @Pete are you sure you don't get any logcat errors when it closes? There is a bug with viewpager which could trigger that.

Comment: no logcat errors at all. could you perhaps link me to the bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` on my second and third activities after I call the new intent.